# Pitfalls of setting Backbone Collection.models versus using Collection.reset

Tags: backbone.js

I hit a performance obstacle when trying to instantiate a `Collection` by passing it directly the list of `Models` or by using `Collection.reset`. It takes about `6000ms` to initialize it with 4800 `Models` with about 200 attributes each. This isn't that large so it's a bit surprising to start off, but going off of this, I tried to speed it up by setting `Collection.models` directly to the array of `models`, and setting `Collection.length` to the `length`.

The question, other than the initial sorting, what is the difference between these two methods and where are the resources being spent? I use `reset` to initialize the Collection so there is no need to remove event handlers on the Models or to clean anything up.

USE CASE:

Trying to display a table with infinite scrolling, where each row is a Model and the Collection is the collection of rows. Each row can have about 200 columns. This is a static table except for a single column which contains a checkbox. The Models aren't doing anything else.

Comment: Are there any listeners bound to the table (e.g., to re-render it when the model list changes?)

Comment: There are but the table handles it since I'm using Handsontable and it keeps events for changing it through their editor.

Comment: Are they queuing events, or is there any chance that items are being re-rendered in response to model events (looking at `"add"` specifically, here)

Comment: They get re-rendered, yeah.

Comment: I haven't tested, but glancing through source that looks like that will mean ~4800 _individual_ redraws as each model is added. If that's what chrome inspector's showing, it may be possible to get time close to 0 by unbinding, adding the models, and re-binding.

Comment: Nah, I'm looking at render time, my entire analysis is on the initialization of the Collection. The attachment into the table happens way later. I'm literally calling `console.time('collection')` before creating the collection, and after creating it. Nothing in between.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit more to collections than their `models` and `length`.

When assigning directly, we're bypassing any other behaviors (sorting, existence-checking, etc) defined by the collection. Both `reset` and the constructor (which ends up delegating to `reset`) use the collection's heavy-ish [`set`](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-83) method to ensure new models are added consistent with the collection's designed behavior.

Direct assignment may be ok if the models will always be `reset` (i.e., not added or removed individually), but certain collection features may exhibit unexpected behaviors if the models are not `set`.

Comment: Well yeah, it's clear that using reset and the constructor do more than just set those two properties. My question was exactly what else happens that could be slowing down the initialization. You mentioned `set`, what happens in there that would make it heavy?

Comment: Checking the linked source, there are several potential O(n) operations over the new models depending on what options are supplied. Can you provide your specific use-case (or a jsperf)?

Comment: Sure, let me add the use case. Also, jsperf has been down for a few days now :/ so if anything a fiddle